# Dismiss a modal from Detail viewController when tapping new item on Master

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a Master -> Detail split view controller with a tableview on the master and a simple view on the detail viewcontroller.  When I tap on an item on the detail view controller a modal vc is presented over the current context (over the detail view controller).  On the iPad when the app is presented in split view, and when I tap on another item on my Master tableView, I would like to be able to determine if a modal vc is present over the detail and dismiss it before presenting the new detail content.
[image: Storyboard Image]

Comment: Ask the detail controller whether its `presentedViewController` is not `nil`. Or never mind that; just tell it to `dismiss`. Does no harm if it's _not_ presenting, so why not? (Awesome diagram by the way)

Comment: Thanks.  That works.
 if let vc = self.presentedViewController as? FooViewController {
            vc.dismiss(animated: true)
}

Comment: Good, so answer your own question and let’s close this out.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple

```
If let vc = self.presentedViewController as? FooViewController { 
vc.dismiss(animated: true) 
}
```